# Invalid argument (HTTP 400): The request contained an invalid argument. When trying to create a new Datastore instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm logged in as the account owner/admin on console.cloud.google.com web control panel. From in there I'm trying to add a new cloud Datastore instance. When I click "Create entity" I get to a page where I have to choose the region from a drop down. No matter what region I choose, I get and error when pressing "next".

The page is showing a spinner for a couple of seconds with "Setting region" (see screenshot). 
[image]

Then it fails with the message: "Invalid argument (HTTP 400): The request contained an invalid argument" (see screenshot). 
[image]

I tried with different browsers too.

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

After a while I ended up running `gcloud app describe` in the cloud console. It told me to first run: `gcloud app create`. After doing that and selecting a region again, I got some more useful error output:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The request contained an invalid argument.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: App Engine does not support project identifiers with a ":" character.
    field: id
```

So apparently the issue was that the `id` of my project had a colon in it - which I don't think I ever choose, it was an old project. Creating a new works :-D